# Translate dynamic exception messages?

Tags: c#, translation, resx

I have some code which catches an exception and displays it to the user. The message is *Field is NULL: Account* for example. Since I dont want to display technical error messages I was looking fir a way to translate this to another language (the users will be German), so I cant display *Account*, I need *Konto* instead for example. So I want to replace *Field is NULL: Account* with something which is easier to understand for the normal user. Whats a good approach to this? I could have some resx files and just say *A field was missing*, but its not telling which one.

Thanks

Comment: Dynamic localisation just doesn't work. Do you have a way of knowing all the possible errors a user could encounter?

Comment: I thought about this as well, but I dont want a mapping for the erros that might come up. Ill proly leave it like it is :).